# Installing ImagMagick and rmagick gem in CentOS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, rmagick

I know this has been asked several times, but the problem is they bring in new versions of rmagick and the older methods are not applicable now.

```
Server - CentOS release 5.6 (Final)
Ruby - ruby 1.8.6 (2007-09-24 patchlevel 111) [i386-linux]
Rails - 2.3.5
```

I tried to install rmagick gem through these steps. I was root user when I executed these queries:

```
yum install ImageMagick.i386
yum install ImageMagick-c++-devel.i386
gem install rmagick
```

The first 2 commands executed smoothly without any errors. On `gem install rmagick`, I am getting this error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for gcc... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes

Warning: Found a partial ImageMagick installation. Your operating system likely has some built-in ImageMagick libraries but not all of ImageMagick. This will most likely cause problems at both compile and runtime.
Found partial installation at: /usr
checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... no
Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. You must have ImageMagick 6.4.9 or later.
```

My question is how can I install a `version > 6.4.9` of `ImageMagick`. Isnt `yum install` supposed to install latest version of ImageMagick? or should I try an older version of `rmagick`gem? In that case, does any one know the older version numbers of rmagick gem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The version of ImageMagick in the CentOS yum repo is outdated. This kind person has provided updated packages: [Problem installing RMagick rubygem on Centos 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254366/problem-installing-rmagick-rubygem-on-centos-5/7766705#7766705)

Comment: i can confirm that the linked answer with the updated imagemagick packages helped me install rmagick succesfully.

Answer (score 2):

you must be root. just run

```
yum -y install ImageMagick-perl
```